# Uploading more than 100 files to github desktop

Tags: git, github

I'm using the Github desktop application for Mac.

I just added a `vendor` file that includes Stripe, which includes hundreds of files.

When I try to commit to master using the app, it won't allow me. I tried using the Github web interface and get an error that I can't upload more than 100 files.

What's the work around for this?

Comment: Use the CLI? `git add ./vendor; git commit; git push`

Comment: @CollinD Thanks. Any reason why I can't authenticate? It asks for my user id and password, but it's not authenticating. I know they both correct (just tested). Could it be because it's private or something?

Comment: Got it...forgot I had 2FA on...needed personal access token. Thanks.